# is a workaround for missing gcc __attribute__((null)) available?

Tags: c, gcc

*gcc* has an attribute **nonnull** which create a warning if an argument signed as **nonnull** tested on NULL… this attribute assume that this argument **never** be NULL.

Ok, I need the opposite: because i want to make my library *NULL-pointer-SAVE*… this mean if I de-reference a pointer marked as **null** without checked to be **NON-NULL** generate a warning:

example:

```
struct TESTS {
  int a1;
  ...
}

void test (struct TESTS *p) __attribute__((null));
...
void test (struct TESTS *p) {
  p->a1 = 5;   // WARNING!! because p is **not** tested on **NULL**
...
```

Comment: Look like more a job for a static code analyzer